# Rethrow Exception with current Item from Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

How do I add information about the current item to an exception in Python? Do I need to wrap it or can I add it to the exception message?

For example:

```
for item in some_list:
    try:
        foo(item)
    except Exception as e:
        # todo: add item info
        raise e
```

I would like to see an exception with the original exception, the item from the loop and the stack trace.

It should show up for unhandled exceptions on the console.

Comment: ``item`` is set outside of the try..except, so yes, you can access it in the ``except:`` block.

Comment: @MikeScotty the question is how do you add this information to the exception in a pythonic way

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the `Exception.args` attribute (note: it's a tuple) which should work for all [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

```
some_list = ["apple", "banana", "stinky socks"]
for item in some_list:
    try:
        if item == "stinky socks":
            raise ValueError("Meh.")
    except Exception as e:
        e.args += (" I don't like {}".format(item),)
        raise e
```

Output (full traceback limited to only the exception):

```
ValueError: ('Meh.', " I don't like stinky socks")
```

---

**Update**: Seems `UnicodeDecodeError` does not re-evaluate the arguments, thus we have to change the properties directly:

```
some_list = ["apple", "banana", "stinky socks"]
for item in some_list:
    try:
        if item == "stinky socks":
            raise UnicodeDecodeError('funnycodec', b'\x00\x00', 1, 2, 'This is just a fake reason!')
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        e.reason = item
        raise e
    except Exception as e:
        e.args += ("I don't like {}".format(item),)
        raise e
```

Output:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'funnycodec' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 1: stinky socks
```

You will find that you have to do special handling for different exceptions, if they do not re-evaluate the args. You can check the exception attributes with `dir(e)` and override them as you see fit.

Comment: my thinking too, a reluctant +1 though because I like bananas!

Comment: @Chris_Rands updated the answer ... can't please everyone ... :P

Comment: This works great for a `ValueError` but does not show up for `UnicodeDecodeError` - do you have a solution that works for all types of exceptions?